# Fetch records after a particular row value in a table column with a limit

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write an sql to tell mysql to fetch the next five records starting from 5 limit 5 from a table like below.

```
srt_id (this is not the auto increment column even though the value is incremented)
------
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8 
  9
 10
```

So over here, I'd like to begin at 6 then end at 10. I might even want to begin at 6 or 7 or 8. I can't use offset 5 or something like that. I have to start at that row and fetch the rest. Can u pls help?

So, I tried:

```
select * from table where srt_id = 5 limit 5; //Begin at 5 and the next 5 records
```

Comment: I'm not very good in SQL commands but the problem here seems to be the fact that you are selecting only rows with `str_id = 5` and eventually if you have 2 or more columns with value of 5 in the `str_id` column you will get 5. Maybe a semi-solution would be to use `str_id >= 5` like the answer below but I thing this will only work if you are sure that you won't have lower values in the next rows.

Comment: Offset exactly does the same `start at that row and fetch the rest` why can't you use offset? `select * from table limit 5,5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where srt_id >= 5 order by srt_id limit 5;
```